# undelete files on ext4

Tags: ext4, undelete

My mother has placed some important files on her /tmp per accident. Now, of course, they are gone.

This happened yesterday (2 boots of the machine since)

I want to try to undelete the files. They were on /tmp, which was on the same partition as the rest of / , so I need a tool that runs on a mounted system (or maybe I could use a livecd ...)

Right now, I am trying testdisk on a systemrescuecd that I just downloaded. I can get some files from /tmp, but not all. (is it the right tool ? What exactly are those "red" files ? are only some of them recoverable ?)

Comment: The best solution is probably a backup and the next best solution for someone who is technically less apt than you perhaps `btrfs` with frequent snapshots. Packages like `restic`, `rdiff-backup`, `duplicity` or `backintime-qt` may also be of interest. None of this is going to help you in retrospect, but perhaps this comment helps future visitors.

Comment: For me `extundelete` segments, while `testdisk` whips out a list of differences. Now to see if it can get the files back.

Answer (score 23):

You can also use [`extundelete`](http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/)

First unmount (`umount`) the file system where the files have been deleted. 
Then read [the chapter **What to do if you've deleted a file**](http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/).

You can install `extundelete` from classic Ubuntu repository:

```
sudo apt-get install extundelete
```

Or better, you can download the [latest version](http://sourceforge.net/projects/extundelete/files/extundelete/) and compile it:

```
cd ~/Download
tar -xf extundelete-*.*.*-.tar.bz2  #Replace *.*.* by the version
cd      extundelete-*.*.*
sudo apt-get install e2fslibs-dev   #Required for compilation
./configure
make
sudo make install
extundelete --version               #Should be your *.*.* version
```

Example of usage: restore all deleted files from directory `Images` into new created directory `restore`

```
sudo extundelete --restore-directory Images/ -o restore /dev/sda3
```

Bad news if you see your file `XXXX` within the following format:

```
Unable to restore inode NNN (Images/XXXX): Space has been reallocated.
```

See all restored files (look for your file):

```
find restore -name '*'
```

Backup your file(s) and remove this temporary directory `restore`

```
cp restore/Images/XXXX MY_BACKUP_DIRECTORY
sudo rm -rf restore
```

Comment: This answer has literally just saved my job. Thankyou.

Comment: I get segmentation fault, core dumped.

Answer (score 13):

Data recovery, especially on EXT file systems, should be attempted from a live CD or other system that isn't depending on the partition you're undeleting from. Getting the disk unmounted or re-mounted as read only helps a great deal in the recovery effort.

Most of the time I try to create an image of the partition or disk using `dd` or a similar tool, so that I'm not working on the disk itself:

```
dd if=/dev/sd[xx] of=/media/backup_drive/recovery.img
```

Once you have your image, you can use a tool like [`ext3grep`](http://carlo17.home.xs4all.nl/howto/undelete_ext3.html) to try and find the files you're looking for. There are lots of different switches that you can try, but this might be a good start:

```
ext3grep --restore-file 'tmp/moms-file.txt' recovery.img
```

The `ext3grep` utility also provides several different ways to search through the file system if you don't know the name of the file. Check `ext3grep --help` for the various methods of searching.

Comment: It would be nice, if you could add the exact steps?

Comment: @saji89 Added a sample usage - also fixed to link to the right utility!

Comment: nice.

now ... does it work with ext4 ?

Comment: @josinalvo I was working with an EXT4 volume when I tried it, and it did work; it didn't find the files I was looking for, but I think I had missed the window of opportunity.

Answer (score 10):

I prefered to use ext4magic as :

```
sudo ext4magic  /dev/sdc3 -r -f $USERl/Documents/ -d /tmp/local/tmp/
```

Note you have to resolv symlink by your own

References:

http://ext4magic.sourceforge.net/howto_en.html

http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext4magic/

http://rzr.online.fr/q/recover

Answer (score 1):

### AnalyzeEXT

Parse data blocks for EXT directory data.

Detailed documentation on EXT4 can be found here:

- https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout
- https://digital-forensics.sans.org/blog/tags/ext4

Download the perl script with

```
git clone https://github.com/halpomeranz/analyzeEXT
```

No guarantee but may be able to reconstruct deleted filesystems.

Comment: What is this tool exactly? How do you use it? I've read the repo description and the [help message in the script](https://github.com/halpomeranz/analyzeEXT/blob/master/analyzeEXT.pl#L20), but there's not much detail.

Comment: Took a look at the perl script; the cli help doesn't match with the script!

Comment: More details are here. I stumbled up on it - never used it! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6pzm6909IvY

Comment: @jouell I've watched 2:30 of the video and he hasn't mentioned the script yet. Could you [edit] your answer to add a brief summary?

Answer (score -1):

I could not recover my crontab file by using ext4magic or extundelete.

On Debian, the crontab for root is here:

```
/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root
```

But, by using the following command, I was able to at least manually recover my crontab from the logs.

```
 grep CRON /var/log/syslog.* -i| awk -F " CMD " {'print $2;'} |sort | uniq
```

It will output only the executed cron jobs (no timings), but at least this is a lot more than starting from scratch.

If you don't remember how often certain cron jobs run, take a full log e.g. syslog.1 and this will give you the count for runs trough the day:

```
grep CRON /var/log/syslog.1 -i| awk -F " CMD " {'print $2;'} |sort | uniq -c |sort -n
```