# Main Pictures and Data folders gone from folder structure - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, directory

Today I've realised that for some reason two of my main system folders (`/home/$USER/Pictures` and `/home/$USER/Data`) have disappeared from my folder structure...

Nautilus has changed how it shows their shortcuts on the side panel, putting them in the section below where personal bookmarks/shortcuts are added, as seen in the picture:
[image: Nautilus view]

None of those shortcuts work any longer, giving me an "unable to find..." error.

Trying to locate the folders using terminal and the find command `sudo find . -type d -name "Pictures"` from the root folder returns nothing, so I guess that means they're gone from my system.

I obviously haven't consciously deleted them (I don't go in there much and I do a lot of my file management from terminal), but you will understand that something like this happening out of the blue is very concerning.

If this has happened to anyone or if it's a known issue, I'd very much appreciate any help to recover the folders (if they can be recovered, which I'm not sure because they're not showing in the trash bin either...)

Comment: The short answer is restore the files from backups. Alternatively take a look at extundelete from this answer. https://askubuntu.com/a/317955/612

Comment: thanks @popey. 
Will try as soon as I get the opportunity with a LiveUSB (since the answer in the link you provided states that the filesystem needs to be unmounted first), and report back if it doesn't work.