# Folder Public is missing

Tags: data-recovery

Today, I turned on my computer (Kubuntu 21.04) and found out that the Public folder is missing. I checked the trash and nothing like this was there. When I turn on VS Code it tries to open the latest script which was in the subfolder of Public. It cannot open it but VS Code shows path:

[image: this is what it shows]

I tried to check history, but no significant changes were found there.

A friend of mine told me that the Public folder is visible for everyone connected to certain network (wifi)- i didn't know that. So my flatmates could possibly delete that, I cant believe it as both of them use Windows and I don't think the could see this folder, but I'm no expert

EDIT
I tried to use testdisk software, however I find nothing that should be highlighted red, no trace of Public folder.
[image: testdisk output]

Comment: It might be useful to add that the last operation when everything was fine was updating some of system features with sudo update. Then the next time I turned on the computer, Public folder was gone

Answer (score 1):

The Public folder is not there because it was deleted somehow.

Recreate the "Public" folder, and then have it recognized as your XDG_PUBLICSHARE folder by editing the configuration file `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`. Make sure there is a line that reads:

```
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. How is it going to bring back my data which was in Public previously?

Comment: Retrieve from your backup. Otherwise it becomes difficult: data recovery with testdisk or some ext4 tools: https://askubuntu.com/questions/217606/undelete-files-on-ext4